# 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'draw'

Tags: python-3.x

Consider:

```
import pygame
import pgzrun
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))

def draw():
    screen.draw.text("Hello", topleft=(10, 10))

draw()
pgzrun.go()
```

I have installed [Pygame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) and pip correctly. I have tried removing line 3, but that gave me a different error.

Comment: Please copy your error here

Answer (score 1):

When using pgzrun, the `Draw()` method is called automatically. The screen object is created in `pgzrun.go()` and is a different type than the pygame screen (surface).

Here is the working code:

```
import pygame
import pgzrun

# screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))   # no need, pgzrun will create screen
def draw():   # called from go()
    screen.draw.text("Hello", topleft=(10, 10))
# draw()  # don't call directly
pgzrun.go()  # initialize screen and main loop
```